# How do you get .env variables to work in ejs files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, dotenv

I am trying to hide an API key and I am attempting to use dotenv to hide them.  Basically everything I try either leads to them being shown in plaintext, getting the "apikey is undefined" error, crashing the entire nodejs server, etc.  Here is the code I am working with:

**.env file**

```
APIKEY="XxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxXxX"
```

**app.js file**

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
require('dotenv').config()
const favicon = require("serve-favicon");

app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, "public", "images", "favicon.ico")));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.render("home", {apikey: process.env.APIKEY});
});
```

and in my **home.ejs** file, I attempt to call that env variable here:

**home.ejs file**

```
var api_key = "<%=apikey%>";
```

This method leads to the API key being linked in plain text (NOT what I want).
[If you view the source of the page following the above method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpwPm.png)

I have also tried doing:

```
var api_key = APIKEY;
```

This leads to the APIKEY is undefined error.  I am relatively new to nodejs/express and I cannot figure this out!  How do I link the APIKEY .env variable to my ejs file, other than linking it in as plain text?  Thank you!

Comment: It appears you determined "_how do you get env variables to work in pjs files_"; But, you must realize that everything you send the browser is going to be available in the browser as text no matter what you prefer to do on the server side. I don't think you've asked the right question.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been facing a similar issue, and it seems ( in my limited understanding) there is no foolproof way to do what you’re asking and totally hide a key that’s accessed by the client browser. However, in your specific usage I believe you mean it is printing the key onto the webpage, which you certainly don’t want. If you remove the the = from your ejs tag it will just reference the js variable rather than rendering it into the page.

<%apikey%>

It will still be accessible via network traffic, but won’t be quite as easily stolen.